# Padding matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, sse, transpose

I try to use SSE to transpose my matrix. But it can only fit matrix whose N is divisible by 4. So I want to pad matrix to reformat it.

For example, if a 3 * 3 matrix, it should pad into 4 * 4 matrix:

```
1 2 3    1 2 3 0 
4 5 6 => 4 5 6 0
7 8 9    7 8 9 0
         0 0 0 0
```

Any efficient way to do this? And I am not sure if cost time padding it, would the SSE transpose be even slower than just loop every index...

Comment: Time to perform an operation is about 1 nsec. Time to access memory is about 70 nsec. Don't optimize until you know what the bottleneck is.

Comment: Just use a structure for the type of your array elements maybe.

Comment: Do you have other things you want to use SSE for as well?  If not, it might not be worth padding your matrix.  Expanding a contiguously-stored matrix separately from transposing it sounds like a huge waste of time.  Why not just do three unaligned loads to get the matrix rows into vector registers, and `insertps` or `blendps` to zero the high element, or just do your shuffling in a way that ignores it?

Comment: Or since a transpose takes a lot of shuffling anyway, maybe do two loads that get the first 8 elements, and a scalar load for the 9th.  Actually, the first and last elements don't move in a transpose, so you just need an 8-element vector shuffle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need to pad, do you?  You're just suggesting that as a way to use a 4x4 SSE transpose routine you already have, right?

A matrix transpose doesn't move the diagonal elements (including the first and last).  A 3x3 transpose has much less data movement: only 7 elements need to be loaded/stored.

```
1 2 3    1 4 7
4 5 6 => 2 5 8
7 8 9    3 6 9
```

### AVX2:

If your elements are 4B (`int` or `float`, not `double`), then the first 8 elements fit in a single AVX vector.  AVX2 has a full lane-crossing shuffle, [`vpermps`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/VPERMPS.html).  So the whole transpose can be done with a single load / `_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps` / store.  It has one-per-clock throughput and three cycle latency on Intel Haswell.

Since the last element doesn't need to move, you don't need to touch it at all, except to copy it if you aren't transposing in-place.

---

With just SSE, you might load two vectors containing the first eight elements and shuffle them with each other using `shufps` or something to combine elements from each vector.

Or maybe shuffle to create a `{ 1 4 3 2 }` vector and a `{ 5 8 7 6 }` vector, and then blend element 7 into the first, and blend element 3 into the 2nd.

**Anyway, a 3x3 is easier to transpose than a 4x4, so don't pad out to 4x4 if you don't need to use SSE on whole rows later.**

Comment: Thanks for your response. And If I want to do matrix addition and multiplication with SSE, is padding worthy? Or loading unaligned and blendps would work better?

Comment: @JenniferQ: Addition doesn't depend on shape, it's the same as adding elements in a flat array.  2 vector and one scalar adds will do the trick there.  IDK about multiply, I haven't worked with 3x3 matrices.  IIRC, the normal way involves a transpose, so you might have an easier time with an unpadded matrix that fits in a register.  Of course, I'm sure lots has been written about this, so you should google up SSE 3x3 matrix stuff, or SIMD in general.

Comment: If you can use AVX2, that gives you a much more powerful shuffle, since it can shuffle all but on matrix element in one vector.  If you find some suggestions to pad 3x3 matrices for SSE, that advice might not apply to AVX2, so keep that in mind.

Comment: I will try to use AVX2, hope it's not too hard to understand... Thanks again for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't pad a matrix efficiently. Assuming flat arrays, you need to create another region of memory, then copy the values into the top left corner, then set the remaining values to zero. So inherently an operation for each value.

What you can do is start with padded matrices and do all operations on them, or use a sparse matrix representation. But since the object is to transpose quickly, it's likely that you'll win on the swings and lose on the roundabouts.

Answer (score -2):

It's an interesting problem to increase the size of an array or a matrix. We can make a new array or matrix that is padded and copy everything to the new.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <histedit.h>
#define MATRIX_SIZE 3 /* use some size */

/* returns an array of arrays of int*, all of which NULL */
int ***alloc_matrix(unsigned rows, unsigned columns) {
    int ***matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof(int **));
    if (!matrix) abort();
    for (unsigned row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        matrix[row] = malloc(columns * sizeof(int *));
        if (!matrix[row]) abort();
        for (unsigned column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            matrix[row][column] = NULL;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

/* deallocates an array of arrays of int*, calling free() on each */
void free_matrix(int ***matrix, unsigned rows, unsigned columns) {
    for (unsigned row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (unsigned column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            //    printf("column %d row %d\n", column, row);
            free(matrix[row][column]);
        }
        free(matrix[row]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}

int *** padding_matrix(int ***matrix, unsigned size, unsigned padding) {
    int ***padded_matrix = alloc_matrix(padding, padding);
    for (unsigned row = 0 ; row < size; row++) {
        for (unsigned column = 0 ; column < size; column++) {
            printf("copying column %d row %d %d\n", column, row,  * matrix[row][column]);
            padded_matrix[row][column] =  matrix[row][column];
            printf("copied column %d row %d %d\n", column, row,  * padded_matrix[row][column]);
        }
    }

    for (unsigned row = size ; row < padding; row++) {
        for (unsigned column = 0 ; column < padding; column++) {
            int i = 0;
            padded_matrix[row][column] = &i;
            printf("padded column %d row %d\n", column, row);
        }
    }

    for (unsigned row = 0 ; row < padding; row++) {
            int i = 0;
            padded_matrix[row][3] = &i;
            printf("padded column %d row %d\n", 3, row);
        }
    return padded_matrix;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int ***matrix = alloc_matrix(MATRIX_SIZE, MATRIX_SIZE);
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    int z = 3;
    int u = 4;
    int w = 5;
    int a = 6;
    int b = 7;
    int c = 8;
    int d = 9;

    matrix[0][0] = &x;
    matrix[0][1] = &y;
    matrix[0][2] = &z;
    matrix[1][0] = &u;
    matrix[1][1] = &a;
    matrix[1][2] = &w;
    matrix[2][0] = &b;
    matrix[2][1] = &c;
    matrix[2][2] = &d;
    for (unsigned row = 0 ; row < MATRIX_SIZE; row++) {
        for (unsigned column = 0 ; column < MATRIX_SIZE; column++) {
            printf("matrix column %d row %d=%d\n", column, row , * matrix[row][column]);
        }
    }


    int ***matrix2  = padding_matrix(matrix, MATRIX_SIZE, MATRIX_SIZE + 1);
    for (unsigned row = 0 ; row < MATRIX_SIZE+1; row++) {
        for (unsigned column = 0 ; column < MATRIX_SIZE+1; column++) {
            printf("padded matrix column %d row %d=%d\n", column, row , * matrix2[row][column]);
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```
padmatrix
matrix column 0 row 0=1
matrix column 1 row 0=2
matrix column 2 row 0=3
matrix column 0 row 1=4
matrix column 1 row 1=6
matrix column 2 row 1=5
matrix column 0 row 2=7
matrix column 1 row 2=8
matrix column 2 row 2=9
copying column 0 row 0 1
copied column 0 row 0 1
copying column 1 row 0 2
copied column 1 row 0 2
copying column 2 row 0 3
copied column 2 row 0 3
copying column 0 row 1 4
copied column 0 row 1 4
copying column 1 row 1 6
copied column 1 row 1 6
copying column 2 row 1 5
copied column 2 row 1 5
copying column 0 row 2 7
copied column 0 row 2 7
copying column 1 row 2 8
copied column 1 row 2 8
copying column 2 row 2 9
copied column 2 row 2 9
padded column 0 row 3
padded column 1 row 3
padded column 2 row 3
padded column 3 row 3
padded column 3 row 0
padded column 3 row 1
padded column 3 row 2
padded column 3 row 3
padded matrix column 0 row 0=1
padded matrix column 1 row 0=2
padded matrix column 2 row 0=3
padded matrix column 3 row 0=0
padded matrix column 0 row 1=4
padded matrix column 1 row 1=6
padded matrix column 2 row 1=5
padded matrix column 3 row 1=0
padded matrix column 0 row 2=7
padded matrix column 1 row 2=8
padded matrix column 2 row 2=9
padded matrix column 3 row 2=0
padded matrix column 0 row 3=0
padded matrix column 1 row 3=0
padded matrix column 2 row 3=0
padded matrix column 3 row 3=0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

You see in the output above that the padded matrix is larger and we  inserted padding.

Comment: Yep, u r right. But if efficiency is what I focus on, 2d array probably should be unrolled and  optimise the for loop.

Comment: What the hell?  Each matrix entry is a separate pointer?  And you're setting the pointers to the addresses of local variables before returning?  There's no way `int i = 0;      padded_matrix[row][column] = &i;` inside a loop can be sane.

Comment: Even apart from correctness, this is horrible for performance.  The matrix should be stored in a flat `int matrix[9]` or `int matrix[16]`, and indexed with `matrix[i*rows + j]`.  Then a transpose-and-expand is just a matter of loading 9 elements and storing 16.  You have not just one but two extra levels of indirection!